# Object used parameter in a method

Tags: java, object

I'm a Java newbie so excuse me if this sounds like a dumb question.
Can someone explain to me what is going on with this method?

```
public static void policyInNoFaultState( AutoPolicy policy ) <===line in question
```

Is "policy" of object type from AutoPolicy? therefore policy inherits everything AoutoPolicy has?
Is this the reason I can use the "Dot" command exp. policy.getAccountNumber(), policy.getMakeAndModel()

I pasted part of the program I think applies to this question.

I appreciate any help you can give.

```
//Creating AutoPolicy ojbects
AutoPolicy policy1 = new AutoPolicy(11111111,"Toyota Camary", "NJ");
AutoPolicy policy2 = new AutoPolicy(22222222, "Ford Fusion", "ME");

//Creating policyInNoFaultState method to display results
  public static void policyInNoFaultState( AutoPolicy policy ){

            System.out.println("The auto policy:");
            System.out.printf("Account #: %d; Car: %s;%nState %s %s a no-fault state%n%n",
            policy.getAccountNumber(), policy.getMakeAndModel(),policy.getState(),(policy.isNoFaultState() ? "is": "is not"));

}//End of policyInNoFaultState
```

Comment: Not an answer, but should point you in the right direction: `AutoPolicy` is the class, `policy` describes one instanc of this class (often called "an object")

Comment: Thank you so much for replying to my question! I understand your explanation on reference part for objects. But I thought objects are created in the form of “Class name obj name = new Class name();”  not within a method statement public static void policyInNoFaultState( AutoPolicy policy ).

Answer (score 1):

A class in Java defines a type and basically acts as template for all instances (objects) created from that class. This template defines data (fields) and behavior (methods) available for all of instances of this type. "Static" members of the type are shared between all instances and non-static members (also called "instance members") are distinct between instances.

Consider the following simple example (beware, this makes no promises about best practices how to define and use classes and instances):

```java
class MyType {
  public static int Shared = 42;
  public int NonShared;

  public void Print() {
    System.out.println("This is me: " + (Shared + NonShared));
  }
}
```

You can create several instances of this class which will all share the same shared field but each have their own value for the instance field:

```java
MyType a = new MyType();
MyType b = new MyType();

a.NonShared = 21;
b.NonShared = 84;

a.Print(); // prints "This is me: 63"
b.Print(); // prints "This is me: 126"

a.Shared = 0;

a.Print(); // now prints "This is me: 21"
b.Print(); // now prints "This is me: 84"
```

`a` and `b` are instances of class/type `MyType`. In a way, `42`, `21`, and `84` are instances of the type `int`.

When you define a method to act on values, you have to specify which kind of values the method should be able to handle. This is done by specifying the type for each of its parameters. Let's have a look at another arbitrary example method:

```java
static String format(MyType object, String info) {
  return info + ".NonShared = " + object.NonShared;
}
```

Above method returns a single instance of type `String` and works one two parameters of type `MyType` and `String` respectively. This is required so that the compiler knows which members (fields or methods) are available for each parameter. Otherwise calling `object.NonShared` would not be possible.

```java
MyType c = new MyType();
c.NonShared = 7;
String formatted = format(c, "formatting");
System.out.println(formatted); // prints "formatting.NonShared = 7"
```

Note that in this simple case, the type of variable `c` matches the type of the parameter `object` exactly. This is not required, you can pass any subtype (or "child class") to the parameter. The parameter's type merely defines the minimum number of members that must be supported by any argument that is passed to the function. You can think of it as a contract between the input parameter and the processing function.

```java
static Integer firstValue(Collection<Integer> list) {
  list.get(0);
}

List<Integers> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
numbers.add(1);
numbers.add(2);

firstValue(numbers);
```

The above code will not work. It will not even compile! Even though `numbers` is an instance of the interface type `List` with concrete implementation type `ArrayList` and has an instance-method `get`, this is not available (nor known) inside the method, which can only work with `Collection` types. The `Collection` type does not define an `get` method, despite implementations of it (sub types, child classes) might provide it.

By using the smallest possible type for any given task, you gain a lot of flexibility. All collections implement the `add` method. By defining a method which can work with `Collection`, you can pass in *any* implementation which adheres to this type and modify it:

```java
static void addValue(Collection<Integer> bag) {
  bag.add(4);
}

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
Queue<Integer> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();

addValue(list);
addValue(set);
addValue(stack);
addValue(queue);
```

I hope this clears things up! If there is any detail that is still unclear, please point it out in the comments and I will try to extend my answer with further points.

Comment: Wow, thank you!  Yes, this helps a lot!  if you don't mind I will copy this to my notes for future reference.  knittl, thanks again for going out your way and explaining this in great detail. 

Peter

Comment: @PeterChabez of course, no problem. Glad to help. If the post answered your question, then don't forget to mark it as accepted, so future visitors will know that this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here "policy" is holding the reference number of an object of "AutoPolicy" type. That is pointing the object passed in parameter.

For better understanding you can go through topic "pass by value and pass by reference in java"

Comment: Thank you so much for replying to my question! So "policy" is an object of class "AutoPolicy". I  understand the reference part in  cases of objects.am used to seeing objects created in the form  Class name obj name = new Class name();